# Change column names in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames `df1` and `df2`. I would like to paste to `df1` column names, `HTO` column content from `df2` that matches the names of the columns from `df1` and row names from `df2`. When `HTO` is missing for a given column in `df1` paste "UN_". Please see an example of a result below

df1

```
        ACG    AGC  ACC  AAC 
gene1   3     2     1    1
gene2   2     1     2    3
gene3   1     1     1    1
```

df2

```
      p      HTO
ACG   0.6    HTO1
AGC   0.3    HTO2
AAC   0.05   HTO1
```

Desired result

```
        HTO1_ACG    HTO2_AGC  UN_ACC  HTO1_AAC 
gene1   3     2     1    1
gene2   2     1     2    3
gene3   1     1     1    1
```

Comment: Can you provide reproducible data? you can use `dput`. We should be able to create the dataframes with the code you provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach, first using a lookup vector with `rename(any_of())` and then renaming all columns which were not renamed with `rename_with()`. This approaches assumes that all columns that haven't been renamed don't contain an underscore `_` in their name.

```r
library(dplyr)

lookup_vec <- setNames(rownames(df2), paste0(df2$HTO, "_", rownames(df2)))

df1 %>% 
  rename(any_of(lookup_vec)) %>% 
  rename_with(~ gsub("(^[^_]*$)", "UN_\\1", .x),
              everything())

#>       HTO1_ACG HTO2_AGC UN_ACC HTO1_AAC
#> gene1        3        2      1        1
#> gene2        2        1      2        3
#> gene3        1        1      1        1
```

Data from OP

```r
df1 <- structure(list(ACG = 3:1, AGC = c(2L, 1L, 1L), ACC = c(1L, 2L, 
                                                              1L), AAC = c(1L, 3L, 1L)), row.names = c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3"
                                                              ), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(p = c(0.6, 0.3, 0.05), HTO = c("HTO1", "HTO2", 
                                                     "HTO1")), row.names = c("ACG", "AGC", "AAC"), class = "data.frame")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

One way in base R is to set a Boolean index `idx` and use `paste0` and `colnames`:

```
idx <- colnames(df1) %in% rownames(df2)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

colnames(df1)[idx] <- paste0(df2$HTO, "_", colnames(df1[idx]))
colnames(df1)[!idx] <- paste0("UN", "_", colnames(df1)[!idx])
```

Output:

```
#       HTO1_ACG HTO2_AGC UN_ACC HTO1_AAC
# gene1        3        2      1        1
# gene2        2        1      2        3
# gene3        1        1      1        1
```

data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(ACG = 3:1, AGC = c(2L, 1L, 1L), ACC = c(1L, 2L, 
1L), AAC = c(1L, 3L, 1L)), row.names = c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3"
), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(p = c(0.6, 0.3, 0.05), HTO = c("HTO1", "HTO2", 
"HTO1")), row.names = c("ACG", "AGC", "AAC"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `match()` to find the rows of `df2` that correspond with the columns of `df1`.  I added the `ACC` row into the data.

```r
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
 ~ACG,    ~AGC,  ~ACC,  ~AAC, 
   3,     2,     1,    1,
   2,     1,     2,    3,
   1,     1,     1,    1)
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)
rownames(df1) <- paste0("gene", 1:3)

df2 <- data.frame(p = c(.6, .3, .05, .1), 
                  HTP = c("HTO1", "HT02", "HT01", "UN"))
rownames(df2) <- c("ACG", "AGC", "AAC", "ACC")

df1 <- setNames(df1, paste(df2$HTP[match(colnames(df1), rownames(df2))], colnames(df1), sep="_"))
df1
#>       HTO1_ACG HT02_AGC UN_ACC HT01_AAC
#> gene1        3        2      1        1
#> gene2        2        1      2        3
#> gene3        1        1      1        1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, where we melt `df1` and then merge on `df2` and pivot back to wide format:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1,keep.rownames = "gene")
setDT(df2, keep.rownames= "seq")

dcast(
  df2[melt(df1, "gene",variable.name = "seq"), on="seq", .(gene, seq=paste0(fifelse(is.na(HTO), "UN", HTO),"_",seq),value)],
  gene~seq
)
```

Output:

```
    gene HTO1_AAC HTO1_ACG HTO2_AGC UN_ACC
1: gene1        1        3        2      1
2: gene2        3        2        1      2
3: gene3        1        1        1      1
```

A similar approach using dplyr/tidyr is as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
left_join(
  pivot_longer(as_tibble(df1,rownames = "gene"), -gene, names_to = "seq"),
  as_tibble(df2, rownames="seq")
) %>% 
  mutate(seq = paste0(if_else(is.na(HTO), "UN", HTO),"_", seq)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = gene, names_from = seq,values_from = value)
```